# WEKA Command Line Parameters

Tags: neural-network, weka

I am able to run Weka form CLI using below command:

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -t Dataset.arff
```

[Weka Explorer Target Selection Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmyKh.png)

How can I set the Target Parameters for example "Number of time units for forecast" using command Line?

We are trying to use command line to improve memory utilization , we have a large dataset with 10000 attributes which is causing Java Heap Space everytime we run it from GUI.

Thanks For the response.

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar with that, but after a quick glimpse at http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/MultilayerPerceptron.html : Are you sure that this parameter is related to the MultilayerPerceptron? It seems to go into some evaluator (at least, that's what it looks like in the source code at https://github.com/bnjmn/weka/blob/50af966d2f72a6d23a04fd1d575acde9ab6f1111/packages/internal/timeseriesForecasting/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/timeseries/gui/SimpleConfigPanel.java#L143 )

Comment: Hi Marco,  yes it is not related to MultiLayerPerceptron , but the output when running from GUI and when run from CLI is totally different, which is where I thought maybe some way I can specify those parameters also and then compare the output.

Comment: (Sorry some guesswork here, until someone can answer properly: ) Is there a panel where you dedicatedly set the parameters of the MultilayerPerceptron? It has **many** parameters, and some of them have strong effects on the outcome (at least that's something I know). Maybe you see differences between the parameters in the GUI and those that are said to be the "defaults" in the JavaDoc of MultilayerPerceptron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting answer to my own question:

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.Run weka.classifiers.timeseries.WekaForecaster -W "weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -L 0.01 -M 0.2 -N 5000 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H 20 " -t <dataset file> -F <FieldList>  -L 1 -M 3 -prime 3 -horizon 6
```

We can always get more help using :

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.Run -h
```